# How to append the response result on the specific class using laravel and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have problem regarding on real time count of likes using ajax and laravel, so once the response success the result of response will append to the specific class, however it happen when i click the like button. each class added the result. to understand more well. please see the attached images below.
w

**Problem: How to append the result on the specific like button.**

**illustration:**

[image: Added the response to all looped class data]

**Html Loop Data:**

```
 echo '<a class="nav-link btn_like_each_content" data-attri-like-content="'.$latest_news_data->content_id.'" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;" ></i> <label class="total_count_of_like_each_content" >0</label> Likes</a>';
```

**Front End:**

```
$('a.btn_like_each_content').on('click',function(){

    var content_id = $(this).attr("data-attri-like-content");


    var data = content_id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/total_count_like_each_comment",
        type:'post',
        data:{like_id:data},
        success: function( response ) {

            if(response == 'Clicked') {

              $.ajax({
                url:"/retrive_like_count_each_content",
                type:'get',
                data:{content_id: data},
                dataType:'JSON',
                success:function(res) {

                    var total_count_of_specific_content = res[0]['count_like'];

                    var parseTotalLike = parseInt(total_count_of_specific_content);
                    $('.total_count_of_like_each_content').text( parseTotalLike );



                },
                error:function(err) {
                  alert('Failed To Insert');

                }

              })

            }

        }
    });


  });
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a unique id to each class

```
echo '<a class="nav-link btn_like_each_content" id="content_'.$latest_news_data->content_id.'" data-attri-like-content="'.$latest_news_data->content_id.'" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;" ></i> <label class="total_count_of_like_each_content" >0</label> Likes</a>';
```

Now Track which content was clicked by defining a variable

```
$('a.btn_like_each_content').on('click',function(){

var content_id = $(this).attr("data-attri-like-content");

var actual_content_id = $(this).attr("id");

var data = content_id;

$.ajax({
    url: "/total_count_like_each_comment",
    type:'post',
    data:{like_id:data},
    success: function( response ) {

        if(response == 'Clicked') {

          $.ajax({
            url:"/retrive_like_count_each_content",
            type:'get',
            data:{content_id: data},
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(res) {

                var total_count_of_specific_content = res[0]['count_like'];

                var parseTotalLike = parseInt(total_count_of_specific_content);
                $('#' + actual_content_id).text( parseTotalLike ); //Pass actual content ID here



            },
            error:function(err) {
              alert('Failed To Insert');

            }

          })

        }

    }
});
```

});